# three.js Object removed from scene is still being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to display some text as a sprite in three.js and want to move the sprite with an object. So I use a canvas to create texture which is used to map SpriteMaterial and then create sprite from it. Then I remove the sprite when I move the object and add a new one with updated text. But problem is, the removed sprite is still displayed even after removal. Also I want to know if there is a better way to perform the thing I want to do. Here is my code to create the sprite:

```
function makeTextSprite(theMessage, theParameters) {
    if (theParameters === undefined) theParameters = {
    };

    var fontface = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("fontface") ?
       theParameters["fontface"] : "Arial";

    var fontsize = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("fontsize") ?
       theParameters["fontsize"] : 18;

    var borderThickness = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("borderThickness") ?
       theParameters["borderThickness"] : 4;

    var borderColor = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("borderColor") ?
       theParameters["borderColor"] : {
          r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0
       };

    var backgroundColor = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("backgroundColor") ?
       theParameters["backgroundColor"] : {
          r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 1.0
       };

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = "Bold " + fontsize + "px " + fontface;

    // get size data (height depends only on font size)
    var metrics = context.measureText(theMessage);
    var textWidth = metrics.width;

    // background color
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + backgroundColor.r + "," + backgroundColor.g + ","
                           + backgroundColor.b + "," + backgroundColor.a + ")";
    // border color
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + borderColor.r + "," + borderColor.g + ","
                           + borderColor.b + "," + borderColor.a + ")";

    context.lineWidth = borderThickness;


    // text color
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)";

    context.fillText(theMessage, borderThickness, fontsize + borderThickness);

    // canvas contents will be used for a texture
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas)
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial(
          {
             map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: true
          });
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
    sprite.scale.set(100, 50, 1.0);
    return sprite;
 }
```

Here is my code to update the text and position of the sprite:
function setCoordinatePosition()

```
{
    if(scene.getObjectByName('text')!=undefined)
    {
        scene.remove("text");
    }

    var sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var coordinate_info = "(" + (vx/100)*sliderValue + ", " + (vy/100)*sliderValue + ", " + (vz/100)*sliderValue + ")";  
    text = makeTextSprite(coordinate_info,{ fontsize: 50, borderColor: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0 }, backgroundColor: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 0.8 } , borderThickness: 5});
    text.name = "text";
    scene.add(text);
    text.position.set(sphere.position.x,sphere.position.y,sphere.position.z);

    text.position.y += 5;
    render();
}
```

And here is the result I am getting:
[image]

I want that red text to display the coordinates of the yellow sphere and follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scene.remove needs a reference to the object, not the name

`scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName('text'));`

instead of

`scene.remove("text");`

Scene is an instance of Object3D so it uses [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.remove) method

If what you are trying to achieve is to move the text along with the sphere you can simply add the text as a child of the sphere using [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add) method. You will also have to adjust relative position.

```
sphere.add(textSprite)
```

Comment: also is what I am doing the best way to do or is there a better way?

Comment: also, that isn't working as well, the object is still being rendered

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve but i can tell you there are many ways to do it and its up to you to make it the best for your context

Comment: what are you getting when you console log getObjectByName? if you can provide jsfiddle i will fix that for you

Comment: I am trying to display the coordinates of the sphere above it in a way that they move along with the sphere. the yellow sphere in the image

Comment: why would you need to remove text every time you set a new position?

Comment: I dont know how to change the text in the sprite. the code is using canvas to create a texture which is inturn used to make the sprite. I don't know how to get the canvas back and change it's text

Comment: Sprite {uuid: "9E485BA8-AADD-4937-B4A3-3B454BE22657", name: "text", type: "Sprite", parent: Scene, children: Array(0), …} this is the console log

Comment: i updated the question to fit your needs, if you can provide a jsfiddle that would be helpful

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Gameatro/hs6dzfc2/3/ I created this fiddle but some things are not working properly there. I am new to web development so I dont have much experience with jsfiddle

Comment: i dont have time right now, but i suggest you look into this example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=transform#misc_controls_transform which should suit your needs if you add text as a child of sphere as described in my answer

Comment: I am trying to use textgeometry for that. But problem is I am not able to find a way to change thickness of the text, so if the size is made small, all the holes in the text stick together

Comment: this is not related to this question anymore, please consider creating a new one